# Proving that uniquely divisible torsion group is trivial in case of $H^r _{cts}(G,\mathbb Q)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, group-cohomology, profinite-groups, galois-cohomology

$G$ be a profinite group. I want to see that the profinite cohomology group $H^2_{cts}(G, \mathbb Q ) $ is $0$.

Using inflation maps we see profinite cohomology group as direct limit of cohomology groups $$ H^r _{cts}(G,\mathbb Q)= \varinjlim _H H^r(G/H,\mathbb Q ^H)$$
where $H$ runs through the open normal subgroups of $G$. These open normal subgroups have finite index as profinite groups are compact thus $G/H $ is finite. For $r>0$ $[G:H] H^r(G/H,\mathbb Q^H) =0$. So $ H^r _{cts}(G,\mathbb Q)$ is torsion.
$\mathbb Q$ is uniquely divisible. Hence so is $H^r(G/H,\mathbb Q ^H)$. Suppose for element $y$ of this group $ay=0$. But multiplication by $a$ is isomorphism so $y=0$.

Have I got it right ?

Comment: This seems OK to me, but I would have written it a bit differently (although the arguments will essentially be the same). First, what you call "continuous cohomology" is officially callled "galois cohomology" (inverse limits of finite  groups acting continuously on direct limits of modules), see e.g. Serre's book bearing the same name. The main reason is that galois cohomology is a cohomological functor, exactly as finite group cohomology, meaning that it transforms short exact sequencs of modules into infinite (a priori) long exact sequences. This is not the case for some other ...

Comment: other "continuous cohomologies", e.g. profinite groups acting on inverse limits of modules.

Second, apply directly the property of unique divisiblity of $\mathbf Q$, i.e. for any integer $n \ge 1$, multiplication by $n$ is a $G$-module automorphism of $\mathbf Q$ (you didn't define the $G$-action, but this doesn't matter), which induces an automorphism of the cohomology group $H^r(G,\mathbf Q)$. But $H^r(G,\mathbf Q)$ is the direct limit of $H^r(G/H,\mathbf Q^H)$, which are torsion (your argument), and we are done.